# How to store production secrets in an ASP.NET Core 2.0 using environment variables?

Tags: asp.net-core

From what I have read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio), the recommendation is to use the **secret manager** to store secrets during development and then use **environment variables** when you deploy to IIS. I am not quite sure what is the best way to go about this - I need to be able to set the same variable to different values in different IIS applications so a system wide environment variable setting is not going to work.

I understand that I can set variables for the application in `web.config` but VS overwrites `web.config` on the server even if there is no `web.conifg` in the project when you do a web deploy. I know it may not be good practice to use web deploy to deploy to production but we want to do it for staging environments etc.

Is there a way to stop web deploy from overwriting `web.config` if it already exists on the target site?

Comment: Use appsettings.json instead of web.config
Put the environment specific values of those app settings in the user secrets during development, and put them with values of your choice for each of these apps. There is a setting in the project file by which you can skip overwriting the appsettings.json file during deployment by skipping the file during publish.

Comment: I looked for the setting to prevent overwriting of appsettings.json but couldn't find it. Where do I set it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Web.config is not used by ASP.NET Core. It's added as part of publishing for compatibility with hosting in IIS only. It's not intended for you to modify or use in any meaningful way.

The built in options for config providers in ASP.NET Core are: JSON, command-line arguments, User Secrets, environment variables and Azure Key Valult. However, User Secrets is only for development, and command-line arguments are difficult to utilize when hosting in IIS. (Technically, you can actually modify the Web.config to add command-line arguments, but as mentioned, that'll be overwritten on the next publish, so it's not the most tenable approach.)

Of the remaining choices of JSON, environment variables, and Azure Key Vault, only Azure Key Vault supports encryption. You can utilize Azure Key Vault whether you're actually hosting in Azure or not, but it's not free. It's not really expensive either, though, so it might be worth looking into.

JSON is probably the worst option, security-wise, mostly because it requires you to actually store your secrets in your source control, which is (or should be) a non-starter. Environment variables, while not encrypted, can be protected. However, it's difficult (though technically not impossible) to run multiple apps on the same server if they each require different secrets for the same environment variables. You can technically set environment variables at a user-level, and then you can also assign an app pool to run as a specific user. That's a lot of setup though.

That said, it's also entirely possible to create your own config providers, which means you can technically use whatever you like. For example, you can write a SQL Server config provider and then store your credentials there. You'd still need to config the connection string somewhere, but perhaps you could use the same connection string for the config for all the sites.

Comment: `JSON is probably the worst option, security-wise, mostly because it requires you to actually store your secrets in your source control` it shouldn't do. Generate it on your release pipeline at the latest possible time.

Comment: @Chris Pratt - it should be possible to set environment variables per process at least in principle right? Am assuming that is what happens when you  set them in web.config. If there is no way to set them per application then how are we supposed to set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to different values or it expected that it set on per server basis? It seems a bit unsatisfactory that web.config is overwritten during deployment if ASP.NET Core doesn't even use it.

Comment: @Mardox - I would be interested to hear about what kind of tools I use to create the kind of release pipeline you have in mind. Am thinking we can put general config settings in appsettings.json which is checked into source control and then put the secrets in appsettings.production.json which is generated as you suggest.

Answer (score 4):

- web.config cannot be used for secrets as it's a non-encrypted plain text file
- any other file config sources (like `appsettings.json`) that could be added via new Configuration API cannot be used until they are not encrypted.
- it is OK to use environment variables, but only if you can guarantee that it's not possible to do a snapshot of env variables on prod machine. Look into [Environment Variables Considered Harmful for Your Secrets](http://movingfast.io/articles/environment-variables-considered-harmful) for more details about this risk.
- if you are hosting on Azure, look into [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/)
- there are a lot of tools/services, like [Hashicorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io) that helps to deal with sensitive data

Comment: +1. I liked Hashicorp Vault, but then you have additional failure point. Having said, you can't discount security features for less work. It may cost huge money to the organization if not handled properly.

Comment: The link to environment-variables-considered-harmful is broken.